# UniTest viewModel when using Deferred in Coroutines and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I want to write a unitTest for my viewModel class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var context: Application
    @Mock
    private lateinit var api: SuperHeroApi
    @Mock
    private lateinit var dao: HeroDao

    private lateinit var repository: SuperHeroRepository
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private lateinit var heroes: List<Hero>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        val localDataSource = SuperHeroLocalDataSource(dao)
        val remoteDataSource = SuperHeroRemoteDataSource(context, api)

        repository = SuperHeroRepository(localDataSource, remoteDataSource)
        viewModel = MainViewModel(repository)

        heroes = mutableListOf(
            Hero(
                1, "Batman",
                Powerstats("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                Biography("Ali", "Tehran", "first"),
                Appearance("male", "Iranian", arrayOf("1.78cm"), arrayOf("84kg"), "black", "black"),
                Work("Android", "-"),
                Image("url")
            )
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun loadHeroes() = runBlocking {
        `when`(repository.getHeroes(anyString())).thenReturn(Result.Success(heroes))

        with(viewModel) {
            showHeroes(anyString())

            assertFalse(dataLoading.value!!)
            assertFalse(isLoadingError.value!!)
            assertTrue(errorMsg.value!!.isEmpty())

            assertFalse(getHeroes().isEmpty())
            assertTrue(getHeroes().size == 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I receive following Exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sample.android.superhero.data.source.remote.SuperHeroRemoteDataSource$getHeroes$2.invokeSuspend(SuperHeroRemoteDataSource.kt:25)
    at |b|b|b(Coroutine boundary.|b(|b)
    at com.sample.android.superhero.data.source.SuperHeroRepository.getHeroes(SuperHeroRepository.kt:21)
    at com.sample.android.superhero.MainViewModelTest$loadHeroes$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModelTest.kt:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sample.android.superhero.data.source.remote.SuperHeroRemoteDataSource$getHeroes$2.invokeSuspend(SuperHeroRemoteDataSource.kt:25)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

And here is my RemoteDataSource class :

```
@Singleton
class SuperHeroRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val api: SuperHeroApi
) : SuperHeroDataSource {

    override suspend fun getHeroes(query: String): Result<List<Hero>> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val response = api.searchHero(query).await()
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body()?.response == "success") {
                Result.Success(response.body()?.wrapper!!)
            } else {
                Result.Error(DataSourceException(response.body()?.error))
            }
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            Result.Error(
                DataSourceException(context.getString(R.string.no_internet_connection))
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Result.Error(DataSourceException(e.message ?: "unknown error"))
        }
    }
}
```

When we use `Rxjava` we can create an Observable as simple as :

```
val observableResponse = Observable.just(SavingsGoalWrapper(listOf(savingsGoal)))
`when`(api.requestSavingGoals()).thenReturn(observableResponse)
```

How about `Deferred` in Coroutines? How can I test my method :

```
fun searchHero(@Path("name") name: String): Deferred<Response<HeroWrapper>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is to inject a `CoroutineContextProvider` and provide a `TestCoroutineContext` in test. My Provider interface looks like this:

```
interface CoroutineContextProvider {
    val io: CoroutineContext
    val ui: CoroutineContext
}
```

The actual implementation looks something like this:

```
class AppCoroutineContextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider {
    override val io = Dispatchers.IO
    override val ui = Dispatchers.Main
}
```

And a test implementation would look something like this:

```
class TestCoroutineContextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider {
    val testContext = TestCoroutineContext()
    override val io: CoroutineContext = testContext
    override val ui: CoroutineContext = testContext
}
```

So your `SuperHeroRemoteDataSource` becomes:

```
@Singleton
class SuperHeroRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
        private val coroutineContextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider,
        private val context: Context,
        private val api: SuperHeroApi
) : SuperHeroDataSource {

    override suspend fun getHeroes(query: String): Result<List<Hero>> = withContext(coroutineContextProvider.io) {
        try {
            val response = api.searchHero(query).await()
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body()?.response == "success") {
                Result.Success(response.body()?.wrapper!!)
            } else {
                Result.Error(DataSourceException(response.body()?.error))
            }
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            Result.Error(
                    DataSourceException(context.getString(R.string.no_internet_connection))
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Result.Error(DataSourceException(e.message ?: "unknown error"))
        }
    }
}
```

When you inject the `TestCoroutineContextProvider` you can then call methods such as `triggerActions()` and `advanceTimeBy(long, TimeUnit)` on the `testContext` so your test would look something like:

```
@Test
fun `test action`() {
    val repository = SuperHeroRemoteDataSource(testCoroutineContextProvider, context, api)

    runBlocking {
        when(repository.getHeroes(anyString())).thenReturn(Result.Success(heroes)) 
    }

    // NOTE: you should inject the coroutineContext into your ViewModel as well
    viewModel.getHeroes(anyString())

    testCoroutineContextProvider.testContext.triggerActions()

    // Do assertions etc
}
```

Note you should inject the coroutine context provider into your ViewModel as well. Also `TestCoroutineContext()` has an `ObsoleteCoroutinesApi` warning on it as it will be refactored as part of the structured concurrency update, but as of right now there is no change or new way of doing this, [see this issue on GitHub for reference](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/541).

Comment: +1 for your help until now. `repository.getHeroes(anyString()` is a suspend function. So it should be called in `runBlocking`. When I run the test, it never ends. Do you know why?

Comment: It get stuck on this line : `when(repository.getHeroes("Batman")).thenReturn(Result.Success(heroes))`

Comment: Ah yes, unfortunately you'll still have to wrap your `when` and `verify` blocks in `runBlocking`.

Comment: But again it gets stuck on following line. I pushed the code on local unit test branch in github which I shared in the question. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: I pulled and looked at it. There were a few things going on I didn't see before.  Primarily, `SuperHeroRepository` isn't a mock, so `\`when\`` is blocking on it as it's trying to run the actual invocation. The cleanest way to mock `SuperHeroRepository` would be to make it an interface. Also, `triggerActions` should only be made after the `viewModel.showHeroes` call.